# Image storing in Database using PHP error

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make profile page in PHP where I should display information of Logged in user including profile photo for that purpose. I want to store uploaded image in database. I have written script but it give me some error in SQL statement.

My php script

```
<?php
include("configdb.php");
    function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }
     }
if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {
    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "../Photos/".$imagename;
if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {
    $query_upload="INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES
('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
    mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error()); 
}else{
   exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
}
}
?>;
```

I got following error

> error in INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES ('../Photos/03-10-2016-1475478958.jpg','2016-10-03') == ----> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES ('../Photos/03-10-2016-14' at line 1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing Mysqli with Mysql try like this

```html
 $query_upload="INSERT into images_tbl (`images_path`,`submission_date`) VALUES
('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";    
mysqli_query($conn,$query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysqli_error($conn));
```

instead of

```html
 $query_upload="INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES
('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
    mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using quotes around the tablename and columns where it should be backticks, so change:

```
$query_upload="INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES
('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
```

to

```
$query_upload="INSERT into `images_tbl` (`images_path`,`submission_date`) VALUES
('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
```

That said, the code is vulnerable to sql injection and you are using the now deprecated and obsolete `mysql_*` functions - change to eitehr `mysqli` or `PDO` and begin using prepared statements.

---

As your db connection is `mysqli` you need to use `mysqli_query` and other associated functions and not mix them with the older `mysql` functions.

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query_upload) or die('error');
```

Comment: Sir still got error in INSERT into `images_tbl` (`images_path`,`submission_date`) VALUES ('../Photos/03-10-2016-1475479781.jpg','2016-10-03') == ----> No database selected

Comment: Can you therefore share the `configdb.php` code too

Comment: <?php 
  $servername="localhost";
 $username="root";
 $password="";
 $dbname = "firstdb";
 $conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
 if($conn->connect_error)
 {
 die("connection failed".$conn->connect_error);
 }
 echo "Connected Successfully";
 

 
?>

Comment: You are mixing `mysqli` and `mysql` functions

Answer (score 1):

You have error in your mysql query, no need to use singlequotes for table name in query use backtick

```
$query_upload="INSERT into `images_tbl` (`images_path`,`submission_date`) VALUES
('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
```

or use without any quote or backtick.

```
$query_upload="INSERT into images_tbl (`images_path`,`submission_date`) VALUES
('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
```

Comment: still have error    INSERT into images_tbl (`images_path`,`submission_date`) VALUES ('../Photos/03-10-2016-1475479848.jpg','2016-10-03') == ----> No database selected

Comment: check your configdb.php is including or not ? or you have selected the correct database or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following query, I am sure it will work.

```
$query_upload="INSERT INTO `images_tbl`(`images_path`, `submission_date`) VALUES ('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
```

The name of table and columns should not be surrounded by quotations. Instead either use backtick or nothing.

**Note:**

`mysql_*` is deprecated as of [php-5.5](/questions/tagged/php-5.5). So instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.
[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Comment: i have applied that before but got Mysqli and Msql Mixing error Thanks any ways solved now